# How do I copy current folder name to the command line of Midnight commander?

Tags: mc

I need something similar to ctrl+enter in total commander, copy current selected folder name in the panel to the command line

Comment: This is not a programming question according to the [help] guidelines, and is off-topic here. Questions about general computer, software, and operating systems are more suited for [su].

Answer (score 12):

In some terminals (default configuration of Windows Terminal) you cannot use:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+something combinations
- modifier+<kbd>Enter</kbd> combinations

For such cases there are these sequences:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+)<kbd>t</kbd> --- copy the file (dir) name from the cursor to the command line
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+)<kbd>p</kbd> --- copy the panel's directory path to the command line

Answer (score 5):

Try the shortcut:

<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The following combination does this: Alt+Shift+Enter